# How can creat a path to my data for my CNN in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

## Intro and setup

So I have been for some time now trying to make a simple Convolution Neural Network. I followed a simple tutorial, which can be found Here's [a link](https://medium.com/nybles/create-your-first-image-recognition-classifier-using-cnn-keras-and-tensorflow-backend-6eaab98d14dd)!

It is a simple cat vs dog test (2 categories)

I have set my jupyter/tensorflow/keras up in
C:\Users\labadmin

What i have understood is that i just have to put the path from labadmin in order to implement my data for testing and training.

Since i am not sure what is causing the error i have pasted the whole code and error, i think it is about the system not getting the data.

The folder with the Data set-up as following:

labadmin has a folder called data withing that there are two folders

- training
- test

Both cat images and dog images are shuffled in both folders. There are 10000+ pictures in each folder, so there should be enough,

## This is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense 
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
 
classifier.add(Flatten())
 
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data\\training',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data\\test',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)

from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=8000,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data = test_set,
        validation_steps = 800)

import numpy as np
from keras_preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('data\\random.jpg', target_size=(64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0]>= 0.5:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
print(prediction)
```

## I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\labadmin\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:26: UserWarning: Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3..., activation="relu")`
C:\Users\labadmin\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:35: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(activation="relu", units=128)`
C:\Users\labadmin\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:36: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=1)`

Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Epoch 1/10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-393aaba195e9> in <module>
     82         epochs=10,
     83         validation_data = test_set,
---> 84         validation_steps = 800)
     85 
     86 # Our image we now send through to test

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    179             batch_index = 0
    180             while steps_done < steps_per_epoch:
--> 181                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
    182 
    183                 if not hasattr(generator_output, '__len__'):

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in get(self)
    707                     "`use_multiprocessing=False, workers > 1`."
    708                     "For more information see issue #1638.")
--> 709             six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in get(self)
    683         try:
    684             while self.is_running():
--> 685                 inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
    686                 self.queue.task_done()
    687                 if inputs is not None:

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    117         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    118         try:
--> 119             result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    120         except Exception as e:
    121             if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in next_sample(uid)
    624         The next value of generator `uid`.
    625     """
--> 626     return six.next(_SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid])
    627 
    628 

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     98 
     99     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 100         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    101 
    102     def next(self):

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in next(self)
    107         """
    108         with self.lock:
--> 109             index_array = next(self.index_generator)
    110         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    111         # so it can be done in parallel

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in _flow_index(self)
     83                 self._set_index_array()
     84 
---> 85             current_index = (self.batch_index * self.batch_size) % self.n
     86             if self.n > current_index + self.batch_size:
     87                 self.batch_index += 1

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What returns when you, in a new cell, run os.listdir("data\\training") ?

Comment: ERROR:root:File `'os.listdir("data\\\\training").py'` not found.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the working directory vs. the folder location. If you run os.listdir(os.getcwd()), and the "data" folder isn't listed then that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you populate your `data\\training` and `data\\test` directories? From the output:

> Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
>   Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
>   Epoch 1/10

it appears that your data augmentation generator did not find any images and the resulting dataset is empty; consequently, when Keras tries to run the `fit_generator`, you get the division by 0 error as it tries to iterate through your null image set.

Comment: What do you mean with populate? If it contains pictures, then yes :)